# How to set up Postfix to save the message body in the log file?

Tags: linux, email, centos, postfix

I need all the body of incoming and outgoing messages are written to the log file. How to setup Postfix to do that?

Answer (score 0):

From [the same question at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/183283/how-to-log-full-outgoing-mails-in-postfix):

> You can use a content filter that stores a copy of the mail somewhere. There is pretty good documentation on it at http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html. It also contains an example content filter script that does exactly what you want.